# Can I use ''and'' in a conditional clause?

Tags: grammar

Can I use ''and'' in a conditional clause ?
for instance :
if you had exersised, and had followed a healthy diet, you would be fit

Comment: Yes, of course. Mind your spelling and punctuation, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best usage, your "if...then" statement should include an explicit "then" before the dependent clause.

> ...if you had exer[c]ised and had followed a healthy diet, then you would be fit.

Comment: Can I use one ''had'' for the two sentences, in formal situations ? : if you had exercised and followed a healthy diet, then you would be fit

Comment: In my opinion, the answer is *No*. Ideally, your example sentence would read "If you had exercised and had followed a healthy diet, then you would be fit."